# C++ Modifying Instance Variable Declared in Superclass

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a couple classes in my C++ app structured like so:

```
           /- RedFixture
 Fixture --
           \- BlueFixture
```

So, the fixture base class has two sub classes.

I want to encapsulate some common functionality inside of the base class, as well as store some common properties. One example is a simple integer that we'll call "current". The base class is declared as follows:

```
class Fixture
{
  public:
    int current;

    Fixture();

    virtual void loop();

    int next();

    int prev();
};
```

The next and previous methods are extremely simple, and literally are composed of some conditions and `current++` or `current--`.

Somewhere else in my code, I have a pointer to a `Fixture`, though the actual type of that pointer could be either `RedFixture` or `BlueFixture`. When I make a call to `fixture->next()`, I am not seeing `current` change inside of either `RedFixture` or `BlueFixture`'s implementation of `loop()`.

`RedFixture`/`BlueFixture` is declared as follows:

```
#ifndef RedFixture_H
#define RedFixture_H

#include "Fixture.h"

class Animation;

class RedFixture : public Fixture {
  public:    
    /**
     * Construct a new fixture
     */
    RedFixture();

    /**
     * Setup the fixture and perform any initialization necessary
     */
    virtual void setup();

    /**
     * Perform the loop
     */
    virtual void loop();
};

#endif
```

Example of `RedFixture`/`BlueFixture`'s implementation of `loop()`, where I access the `current` variable:

```
void RedFixture::loop()
{
  Animation *currentAnim = animations.at(current);
  currentAnim->animate(leds);
}
```

And, at some other point in the code, I have something like this:

```
Fixture *fixture = fixtures.at(0);
fixture->next();
```

I would expect the `current` property to be incremented, and have this reflected the next time `loop()` is called, but this is not the case. Rather, the `current` variable appears not to change.

Given that I am new to C++, am I misunderstanding how inheritance works? Shouldn't the `current` counter be properly modified, even if I'm using polymorphism and calling `next()` or `prev()` on a pointer of the type `Fixture`?

Comment: Can you post an example of your RedFixture and BlueFixture classes? I need to see what your doing in your implementations.

Comment: You must have some other logic error.  If a class inherits from a superclass, and then modifies a member variable inherited from the superclass, it doesn't matter what the static type of the object is, the variable should change - polymorphism should not affect anything, it should only affect what functions are called. Watch your access modifiers,  maybe you're calling the wrong next()?.

Comment: You're not misunderstanding inheritance itself, it should work. Does the implementation of increment change between parent and child classes? Especially, does the child code use some variables that exist only in the child for the conditions etc.?

Comment: @deviantfan I don't see another explanation here, has to be it

Comment: Hmm... That's what I was afraid of. The child classes do not have implementations of next/previous-- there's only one common implementation on the parent.

Comment: Hm. Well, in the current code / question text, I don't see a problem. Are you able to reproduce the error in a small test program with only the necessary classes (and a main to call increment/loop etc.)?

Comment: You aren't really encapsulating your _current_ - you should make it *protected* so derived classes can see&change it but not random external code. But when you say "composed of some conditions and current++ or current--" - are you sure that the conditions are being satisfied?

Comment: @cliffordheath I've also tried removing the conditional entirely and instead of doing an increment, setting the value to some known number-- still no change.

deviantfan: Trying to create a smaller case to reproduce the behavior now.

Comment: @AndrewM Would you add the class declaration for either of the derived classes? Maybe there's something in there that could be the culprit.

Comment: I went ahead and added the whole .h file for the child classes

Comment: I narrowed it down to an issue with a library I am using-- the "other point" in the code where `next()` is actually called. For some reason, that library isn't properly calling `next()` on the instance I thought it was. Will go ahead and do a full writeup when I finish up debugging/fixing.

Comment: @AndrewM Nicely done, I posted an answer with some sample code that may clarify some questions you have about polymorphism, no need to accept/upvote, just adding to the pot

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints:

```
Nothing
1
```

hopefully this answers some of your questions about polymorphism and how it may relate to your code. Sorry if i butchered the intended purpose of your functions but just trying to give you some context.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fixture{
public:
    int current = 0;
    virtual void loop(){ 
        cout << "Nothing" << endl;
    }
    void next(){
        current++;
    }
};


class AwesomeFixture : public Fixture{
    public:
        void next(){
            // Do nothing
            cout << "Nothing" << endl;
        }
        virtual void loop(){
            next();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    Fixture * fixture = new AwesomeFixture();
    fixture->loop();
    fixture->next();
    cout << fixture->current << endl;

    return 0;
}
```